# Deferred EL in JSP 2.0

Tags: jsp, el

Is there a way to use something like deferred EL in JSP 2.0 / J2EE 1.4?  The idea is to pass a test to a tag file and have it display an item in a list (or not) based on the value of the expression.  Basically, I'd like to do something like this:

JSP:

```
<x:myTag items="${myCollection}" test="${item.visible}"/>
```

myTag.tag

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${collection}">
    <c:if test="${test}">
        ${item}
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Upgrading our JSP container is not an option.  Any ideas?

**Update:**

I tried doing this with JSP fragments, but the EL in the fragment was evaluated once in the JSP, rather than once per iteration in the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [jsp fragments](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnaln.html#bnalq). I believe it will not be the extremely elegant solution you would appreciate, but it does allow the execution of the expression to be deferred until inside the tag.

Edit:
You could check out the [variable](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnamu.html#bnank) with the "name-given" setting.

(I will readily admit I did *something* like what you're trying to do about 2 years ago. I have not touched it since. I remember I thought it was quite arcane)

Comment: Ah, I got it to work.  My tag file was missing <%@ variable name-given="item" %>.  It's arcane, but it does work.